# Send file from jsp to Apache Camel servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets, apache-camel

I have a jsp with a file upload form and I want to send this request to Apache Camel servlet, process the request and send the file further to another route.

The input form:

```
<form action="camel/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="desc" />
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Camel servlet route:

```
<route id="uploadRoute" streamCache="true">
  <from uri="servlet:upload?httpMethodRestrict=POST"/>
  <process ref="fileProcessor"/>
  <to uri="direct:inputMessages"/>
</route>
```

In fileProcessor bean I have :

```
public void process(Exchange ex) throws Exception {
HttpServletRequest req = ex.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_SERVLET_REQUEST , HttpServletRequest.class);
        String desc = req.getParameter("desc");
        System.out.println(desc);
        Part part = req.getPart("file");
}
```

here desc is null , and getPart throws exception :

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream closed
```

If I convert the exchange body to String I see valid data :

------WebKitFormBoundaryqMDEm1jQr38BDpYP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="desc"

some description
------WebKitFormBoundaryqMDEm1jQr38BDpYP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myfile.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

End upload
------WebKitFormBoundaryqMDEm1jQr38BDpYP--

I want to set the exchange body to 
part.getInputStream()
and send to the file processing route.

Is this the way to do this ? And how could I solve the above exception ?